# Add new methods to interface or cast the object?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

We have an interface like this?

```
public interface ILicense
{
   bool IsTrial { get; }
   bool IsTrialLicense { get; }
}

public class StandardLicense : ILicense
{
  public bool IsTrial { get { return true; } }
  public bool IsTrialLicense { get { return true; } }
}
```

But now new requirement came for new License (the name is ZLicense) which has additional methods.

- GenerateActivationKey()
- GenerateDeactivationKey()

To sum up how ZLicense must look like:

```
public class ZLicense : ILicense
{
  public bool IsTrial { get { return true; } }
  public bool IsTrialLicense { get { return true; } }
  public string GenerateActivationKey()
  public string GenerateDeactivationKey()
}
```

So I have two options:

- Add two new methods to interface (and make an abstract class)
- Cast the interface and use new two methods

Usage can be used like this:

```
if(ILicense is ZLicense)
{
  ZLicense license = ILicense as ZLicense
  .. can use new methods lile license.GetActivationKey()
}
```

What's best practise approach here?

Comment: `IsTrial` and `IsTrialLicense` look more like `Properties`, not `methods`

Comment: They are properties.

Comment: I don't follow the question, do you own ZLicense or do you just consume it? Anyway, based on what you've shown here, your `ILicense` object will never be of type ZLicense.

Comment: Doing `if(ILicense is ZLicense)` is usually a sign of a code smell (and probably violates SOLID principles)

Comment: This is a decision you're going to have to make based on your specific circumstance. Factors which will play into that decision include how many implementations of ILicense exist and whether you control/own those implementations, whether those methods make sense for the other kinds of licenses, etc. A third option could be introducing a new interface that extends `ILicense`, so you're down-casting based on the interface and not the concrete type.

Comment: Are all classes inherited from `ILicense` should implement `GenerateXXX` methods? Then add to `ILicense`. Not? Then make `interface IGenerate` which may or may not have relationship with `ILicense`.

Comment: @broadband I think the `Strategy Pattern` may be what you are looking for. (https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern)

Comment: You should never need to write `if(ILicense is ZLicense)` because you should have new consumers for `ZLicense`.

Comment: I don't like casting, but the problem is because we're using license like this: License.Instance.MethodName where Instance is this https://pastecode.xyz/view/f77073cf

Answer (score 1):

If each license type implementing `ILicense` should support `GetActivationKey()`, then extend the interface.

If that is true and you have an idea of a default implementation, go with an abstract class.

If only the `ZLicense` has the method `GetActivcationKey()`, then only implement it there (casting will be required).

If there might be some different licenses in the future which might support `GetActivationKey()` but also some without that method, derive a new interface from `ILicense`, for example `IActivatableLicense`. Implementing this interface will then force the developer to implement the activation key handling.

Comment: You seem to be making a distinction between "extend the interface" and "derive a new interface from `ILicense`." Those terms mean exactly the same thing to me. Can you explain?

Comment: "Extend the interface": Add methods to that interface declaration. "Derive a new interface": Create a new interface which derives from the original one (also this is calling "extending") so that you have two interfaces. The second one has additional methods and the ones defined in the original interface.

Comment: Adding methods to an interface breaks existing implementations, so this is generally not an option. (At least [not yet](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/288).)

Comment: It is a general option. That is exactly why I wrote "If **each** license ... should support ...". With that, you force existing implementations to be updated. That's a breaking change. People don't like it but sometimes they are very healthy.

Comment: The idea about ILicenseExtended sounds good to me, because for now my project managar suggested that I put all additional methods and properties to ILicense.